# Repetir componentes a renderizar según valor variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, component, jsx

Estoy avanzando en mi aprendizaje de React, y me he atascado en un **renderizado**

Vale. Mi render se ejecuta bien con lo siguiente:

```
root.render(<div className="creado">
                <Contador />
            </div>);
```

Contador es una función que me devuelve el html necesario para unos botones y un clásico contador realizado con cambios de estado, utilizando el onClick en el tag de los botones.
Hasta aquí todo perfecto.

Los problemas llegan cuando quiero iterar las veces que aparece el contador, que **deben de variar según el dato llegado por el user mediante un prompt.**

Para esto, creo el promt y capturo su valor en una vinculación al cargar la ventana:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () =>{
const Valor = prompt("Introduzca número","2")}
)
```

Y además, creo otro vínculo con la cadena que me interesa **iterar X veces**

```
const componente = <Contador />;
```

De momento, bien. Tengo el dato "componente" que es igual que la anterior cadena:

Funciona correctamente:

```
root.render(<div className="creado">
                    {componente}
                </div>);
```

Y aquí está mi pregunta. ***Cómo demonios itero ese componente mediante su asignación?***

Si el user introduce "3", lo que busco es que el render haga:

```
root.render(<div className="creado">
                {componente}
                 {componente}
                {componente}
            </div>);
```

Es decir, que "componente" se escriba entre las div del render las veces que indique la const Valor.
En este caso, crear 3 contadores, como yo quiero

He probado de todo, y nada tiene éxito. Todo parece interferir con JSX.
ni pasarlo a string y hacer repeat, ni con Symbol, nada de bucles for... o funciones dentro del render. Fuera he intentado, pero al integrar el componente en una función me es complicado dar ese formato que precisa para el render.

**¿Alguien puede ayudarme en desfacer este entuerto?**

No he probado con props, porque entiendo que para este caso no me hacen falta.
¿Es posible que haya un comando específico en React para esto?
He de decir que acabo de empezar con React, haciendo tutoriales e incorporando mis ideas, además de la inestimable práctica que adquiere uno con js. He visto poco más que el render, las props y los estados. Quizás me esté adelantando pero no me puedo quedar con esta duda.

Un saludo y gracias

---

## ***Actualización***

---

Después de decenas de horas, sigo investigando para descubrir de que forma

"multiplicar" el `<Contador />` dentro de un  `root.render()`

en el siguiente código completo de mi experimento:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ytvjwt?file=index.html

@PabloLozano a tratado de ayudarme, pero no conseguimos llegar al resultado que busco. Voy a mostrar mediante imágenes lo que quiero: (huelga decir que los estilos, en este caso, no son prioritarios)
[image: normal]
Lo de arriba es un contador
[image: busco]
Aquí hay 3 contadores
pero no con 3 contadores... con los que introduzca el user en el prompt

Y quiero saber si es posible de la manera descrita, nada de props ni hooks ni keys, que aun no lo he visto, solo con el js.

En lugar de llamar a `<Contador />`
quiero llamar a la repetición de `const componente = <Contador />;`
para en el render hacer un
 `root.render(<div className="creado">{Contador}</div>);`

y poder definir así cuantos jugadores (por ende, contadores) habrá. El contador es el conjunto de botones y el total de cada bloque.

He intentado de todo.
Pasar a array el componente, hacer bucles, agregar componentes al array mediante bucles... nada funciona. En cuanto tiene que pasar el componente, debe de dejar de leerlo como jsx... Y fuera del render nada parece funcionar. En el render, las funciones no hacen lo que deberían con datos jsx, o eso me parece en mi caso.

Intento probar soluciones según avanzo en mi formación autodidacta de React... pero utilizar herramientas que aún no he estudiado no me parece útil. De momento quiero saber si lo que planteo tiene solución sin más herramientas que las utilizadas hasta ahora.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente tener un bucle donde vas generando los elementos que necesitas:

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.cantidad= props.cantidad;
  }
  
  generarElementos() {
    const elementos=[];
    for (let i=0;i<this.cantidad;i++) {
      elementos.push(
        <div>
          <div>Elemento {i}</div>
          <button >Un boton</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
    return elementos;
  }
 
  render() {
    return this.generarElementos();
  }
};

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( <MyComponent cantidad="3" />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Es fácil una vez que conoces como funciona la sintaxis (y semántica) de JSX, pero no te preocupes si tardas un tiempo en acostumbrarte.

En este ejemplo he usado un elemento "nativo" de HTML, pero puedes anidar componentes creados en otra clase sin problema:

```
elementos.push(<MiElemento miProp="datos" />);
```

Puedes encontrar más información en la documentación oficial, con algún ejemplo: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Muchas gracias, Pablo. Desde luego solo me faltó probar esa variante de bucle, crear ese array vacío... Muy interesante.
Ahora bien, me surge otra duda que espero me solventes: Quizás el problema radica en que utilizo las últimas versiones de las bibliotecas de react (18.2 creo) y las que tu usas son 16, y en estas actualizadas el ReactDOM.render ya no funciona.

Comment: Existe algún método con el root.render para hacer lo mismo?
¿Es imperativo utilizar las ultimas librerías?¿La 16 tiene algo en particular? ¿Como elegir la versión adecuada para cada proyecto?

Comment: he usado la 16 porque es la que añade StackOverflow por defecto en los "fragmentos", pero la sintaxis debería ser la misma. Mi recomendación es usar la versión estable más reciente

Comment: He actualizado para usar la última versión

Comment: Muchas gracias. Pinta bien. Voy a probarlo y te digo

Comment: Estoy teniendo problemas. Mi sintaxis inicial es diferente a la tuya. Me dice al colocar la primera expresion que hay problemas con typeScript.
Además, quiero hacerlo sin usar props, sólo la variable externa introducida al cargar el documento.
Creo que lo mejor será que suba el proyecto a codesandbox y lo comparta, para tener todo mas claro. Me pongo con ello

Comment: Stackblitz.com es otra opción, si te gusta VSCode. Si usas typescript recuerda que no es ya JSX, sino TSX

Comment: Sí, uso VSC. Gracias por mencionar ese editor. Muy buen aspecto. ¿Por qué mencionas VCS?¿Es similar?
Te explico un poco. Yo esto de los archivos app.js solo lo he usado para aprender un poco en Node. En mi proyecto tengo una vulgar carpeta estática con 1 archivo html, otro css y el js. Nada más. Lo digo porque veo .JSON y cosas así al empezar a editar en stackBlitz.com Voy a tratar de subirlo ahí y a ver si me puedes echar una mano con el código delante

Comment: Y que yo sepa, no uso typescript
Eso sí, uso babel (lo tengo seleccionado en VCS) y meto la librería de jsx ¿Es lo correcto?

Comment: Aquí está mi código

[enlace](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-ytvjwt?devToolsHeight=33&file=index.html)

Comment: Te he puesto una solución aquí: https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-w5wdn3?file=2.js

Comment: El código del anterior enlace no es lo más elegante (realmente apenas conozco React y no controlo sus "hooks", pero te permite elegir número de botones

Comment: Interesante, pero no busco eso. Como contador me refiero a los 6 botones y el valor actualizado, no solo a los botones de 1 de los jugadores. Voy a actualizar al hilo para agregar mis pesquisas